# why resolv.conf is changing

Tags: linux, rhel, dns, resolv.conf

I am using Red Hat 6.7

when I update my `resolv.conf` file as the following:

```
 options attempts:2
 options timeout:1
 search usa.Pe.corp  tedcruz.usa.fb.corp
 nameserver 10.9.145.145
 nameserver 10.9.100.103
 nameserver 43.11.0.14
```

after **service network restart** I get a different `resolv.conf` file as the following

```
 options attempts:2
 options timeout:1
 search usa.Pe.corp 
 nameserver 10.9.145.145
```

How to **disable**/**block** the `resolv.conf` file from any changing?

Why the file is changing after **network restart** or after **reboot**?

Comment: Is this perhaps a `/etc/resolv.conf` file that has "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN" at the top?

Comment: I update the /etc/resolve.conf on the first time after I installed the linux machine , so this is the first update !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dhclient-script`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient-script) is doing this.  It checks to see what nameservers and domains are visible.  Sometimes that is useful.

According to its manual page,

> When it starts, the client script first defines a shell function, **`make_resolv_conf`** , which is later used to create the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. To override the default behaviour, redefine this function in the enter hook script.
>
> On after defining the make_resolv_conf function, the client script checks for the presence of an executable **`/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks`** script, and if present, it invokes the script inline, using the Bourne shell `'.'` command. The entire environment documented under ***OPERATION*** is available to this script, which may modify the environment if needed to change the behaviour of the script. If an error occurs during the execution of the script, it can set the exit_status variable to a nonzero value, and `/sbin/dhclient-script` will exit with that error code immediately after the client script exits.

For example, as shown in *[How To: Make Sure /etc/resolv.conf Never Get Updated By DHCP Client](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/)*, you can create or append to **`/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks`** this dummy function:

```
make_resolv_conf(){
    :
}
```

Comment: Thomas thx for your solution so create anew file with this content will protect on the resolve.conf from changing, but let me suggest  other option as chattr +i resolve.conf , what you think about this ?

Comment: You can certainly try that, or the dummy function.  I've seen comments about both, where they work for some people and not for others.

Comment: so from your opinion what is the best choice?

Comment: The function is more easily tested: if it works, you can put an "echo" statement in the function to see it working.  The chattr approach is less easily verified.  So I suggested the function.